# Setting headers for streaming mp4 video and playing files with Exoplayer

Tags: android, video, streaming, exoplayer

Api has a token header that i need to set but the video is not encrypted. 
I have two questions:
How can i play .mpg,.mpeg,.3gp,.mov and other files from disk with exoplayer?
How can i set headers with exoplayer and stream mp4 video from url?

Answer (score 8):

```
   // (1) Create method returns  'DataSource.Factory'

     public DataSource.Factory headers() {
            Map<String, String> headersMap = new HashMap<>();
            headersMap.put("iid", "aaa123 ");
            headersMap.put("version", "1.4");
            headersMap.put("agent", "phone");
            headersMap.put("token", "dfdf4f4yt5yf5fh4f5");
            return new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setDefaultRequestProperties(headersMap);
        }
    
    
    
    // (2) Add headers() method call to the player

           SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context)
                    .setMediaSourceFactory(new 
                     DefaultMediaSourceFactory(headers()))
                    .build();
```

Comment: Application is crashing  var headersMap = HashMap<String,String>()
        headersMap.put("clienttoken", client_token)
        var dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, "POC"))
        dataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperties(headersMap)

        exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer .Builder(this).setMediaSourceFactory(DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory)).build()

Answer (score 7):

Figured out the answer:

```
DefaultHttpDataSource source = new DefaultHttpDataSource(userAgent, null);
    source.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "your auth code");
    source.setRequestProperty("Accept", "...");

    ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(uri, source, extractor, 2,
            BUFFER_SIZE);
    MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(sampleSource,
            null, true, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING, 5000, null, player.getMainHandler(),
            player, 50);
    MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource,
            null, true, player.getMainHandler(), player);
```

Answer (score 3):

ON exoplayer 2.13.2, DefaultDataSourceFactory constructor method is deprecated, you can use Factory instead.

```java
val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
                .setUserAgent("")
                .setDefaultRequestProperties(hashMapOf("" to ""))
                .setDefaultRequestProperties(hashMapOf("" to ""))
            val mediaSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(url))
            val player = SimpleExoPlayer
                .Builder(this)
                .build()
            binding.videoPlayerView.player = player
            player.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            player.prepare()
            player.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  // 1. Create a default TrackSelector
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new 
  AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new 
  DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

  // 2. Create a default LoadControl
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

 // 3. Create the player
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector,  
   loadControl);
    simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
    simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView)
  findViewById(R.id.player_view);

  //Set media controller
    simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();

   // Bind the player to the view.
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player); 

   String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    // encrypt Authdata
    byte[] toEncrypt = (username + ":" + password).getBytes();
    encoded = Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new 
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this,   
    "exoplayer2example"));

    DefaultHttpDataSource source = new  DefaultHttpDataSource(Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"),null);
    dataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+encoded);
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://example.com/assets/video/SampleVideo.mp4"),
            dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
    final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);
    exoplayer.prepare(videoSource);
```

Comment: `setDefaultRequestProperty` is deprecated for `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory`

Comment: @Arihant according to  [this issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2714) you can use `HttpDataSource.Factory.getDefaultRequestProperties` and edit them.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i set headers with exoplayer and stream mp4 video from url?

I implemented basic authorisation so:

```
private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private PlayerView playerView;

private void initializePlayer() {
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
            new DefaultTrackSelector(),
            new DefaultLoadControl());
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.seekTo(0, 0);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.media_url));
    MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
    player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
}

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(final Uri uri) {
    HttpDataSource.BaseFactory myDSFactory = new HttpDataSource.BaseFactory() {
        @Override
        protected HttpDataSource createDataSourceInternal(HttpDataSource.RequestProperties defaultRequestProperties) {
            byte[] toEncrypt = uri.getUserInfo().getBytes();
            String encoded = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dsf = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab");
            HttpDataSource ds = dsf.createDataSource();
            ds.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encoded);
            return ds;
        }
    };

    ExtractorMediaSource.Factory emf = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(myDSFactory);
    return emf.createMediaSource(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Exoplayer:2.19.1'** In, My case i had a id and i create a hardCoded url based on ID. The url needed bearer Token and then, return the video.

Here **userAgent is compulsory**. The answer by Jimmy was working.

Error : If you don't mentioned UserAgent

> Unexpected exception loading stream
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty

```
         val httpUrl = RestAdapter.getVideoUrl(id)

        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
            .setUserAgent("Android")
            .setDefaultRequestProperties(hashMapOf("Authorization" to "Bearer "+Prefs.retrieveToken(this)))

        val mediaSource: MediaSource =
            ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(
                     MediaItem.fromUri(httpUrl)
                )
```