# Play Video with Headers in Exoplayer Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a video with some headers files. I want to play that video in Exoplayer. I tried, But some of the methods are deprecated or some do not work.

Video Path: `https://{{account-info}}.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/test/test-video.mp4`

```
String url = "https://{{account-info}}.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/test/test-video.mp4";
simpleExoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).setMediaSourceFactory(new DefaultMediaSourceFactory((headers() /* header method*/ ))).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).setLoadControl(loadControl).build();
        mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url);
        simpleExoPlayer.addMediaItem(mediaItem);
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare();
        simpleExoPlayer.play();

//headers method
private DataSource.Factory headers() {
        Map<String, String> headersMap = new HashMap<>();
        headersMap.put("Authorization", "auth");
        headersMap.put("X-Amz-Content-Sha256", "Content");
        headersMap.put("X-Amz-Date", "20221217T154926Z");
        headersMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setDefaultRequestProperties(headersMap);
    }
```

---

Above code thorows an error that is Source error

Error log:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:641)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:396)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1009)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Any other method to request a Video with Headers and play in Exoplayer?

Thank you :)

Comment: you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162441/setting-headers-for-streaming-mp4-video-and-playing-files-with-exoplayer

Comment: @TanishqChawda Yes, I used that 1st code link https://stackoverflow.com/a/67485026/16765223 but solution not found :(